# How to check user input in a list/tuple?

Tags: python, list, tuples, in-operator

Basically what I want my program to do is:

```
new_ch = input("What channel would you like to switch to?")
if new_ch in channels:
      print("You're now on channel,", new_ch,".")
else:
       print("That's not a valid channel.")
```

No matter what I do, it keeps printing the statement on the false branch "That's not a valid channel". Is there a way I can have my program search my channels list/tuple with the users input? My channels list consists of variable names ex.

```
Ch1 = "Ch1 - Fox News"
Ch2 = "Ch2 - PBS"

Etc.

channels = [Ch1, Ch2, Ch3, ... Ch10]
```

Comment: This works fine for me. If I input `Ch1` then it will switch to "Ch1 - Fox News". Is this not the behavior you expect?

Comment: I expect it to do that, but when I input Ch1, it prints out the false statement. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post the full example, in order? It is working fine for me. Nowhere should print `False` in the example you've provided.

Comment: @Bryana whats your python version ? and whats the format of channels ?

Comment: Ok, I tried to indent the code towards my original the best I can, so one indent might be off. My python version is 3.4.1 @Kasra

Comment: did you exactly print your input by a format like `Ch1 - Fox News` ?

Comment: I typed that in, it doesn't work with the str definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok If the input is "ch1" and you expect the output to be "Ch1 - Fox News", then your if statement is incorrect .

Because you are comparing "Ch1" to ['Ch1 - Fox News', 'Ch2 - PBS'] :

```
>>> channels = [Ch1, Ch2]
>>> channels
['Ch1 - Fox News', 'Ch2 - PBS']
```

So to correct this you need to use a dictionary, here's how :

```
Ch1 = "Ch1 - Fox News"
Ch2 = "Ch2 - PBS"
channels = {"CH1":Ch1,"CH2": Ch2}
new_ch = input("What channel would you like to switch to?")
What channel would you like to switch to?"ch1"
if new_ch.upper() in channels:
    print("You're now on channel,", channels[new_ch.upper()],".")
else:
    print("That's not a valid channel.")


 ("You're now on channel,", 'Ch1 - Fox News', '.')
```

The upper function is just so that it is case independent.

UPDATE

---

To randomize :

```
elif choice == "2":
    ch = random.choice(channels.keys())
    print("You're now on channel", channels[ch],".")
```

To print the list of channels:

```
elif choice == "1":
    print("\n")
    for item in channels:
        print(channels[item])
```

Comment: So I tried as you instructed, but it is still printing my false statement. I also couldn't print out my list of channels, nor use my randomchoice, so I had to make a seperate list, not sure if that would have anything to do with it.

Comment: I didn't put the uppercase letters in the key. This worked perfectly! Thank you very much! @TheCreator232

Comment: @Bryana : Look at the update to solve the issue's . For future reference learn how python dictionary works.